# MultiThreading with Python

Tags: python, multithreading

This is a Producer Consumer Problem. I need a single producer and multiple consumers to access the shared data cell and each consumer needs to access the produced data before the producer makes additional data. The code works fine when there is a single consumer. I have attempted to make a list of the Producer and Consumers in order to .join() and .start() them. The program works so far as the first consumer, but hangs up when it gets to the second consumer. I have tried to change the locking mechanisms from "notify" to "notifyAll" in the getData and setData, I am a beginner in python and this stuff is pretty foreign to me but I have been trying stuff for 10 hours and would really appreciate some help.

```
import time, random
from threading import Thread, currentThread, Condition

class SharedCell(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = -1
        self.writeable = True
        self.condition = Condition()
        
    def setData(self, data):
        self.condition.acquire()
        while not self.writeable:
            self.condition.wait()
        
        print("%s setting data to %d" % \
              (currentThread().getName(), data))
        self.data = data
        self.writeable = False
        self.condition.notifyAll()
        self.condition.release()
    
    def getData(self):
        self.condition.acquire()
        while self.writeable:
            self.condition.wait()
        print(f'accessing data {currentThread().getName()} {self.data}')
        self.writeable = True
        self.condition.notifyAll()
        self.condition.release()
        return self.data
    
class Producer(Thread):
    
    def __init__(self, cell, accessCount, sleepMax):
        Thread.__init__(self, name = "Producer")
        self.accessCount = accessCount
        self.cell = cell
        self.sleepMax = sleepMax
    
    def run(self):
        
        print("%s starting up" % self.getName())
        for count in range(self.accessCount):
            time.sleep(random.randint(1, self.sleepMax))
            self.cell.setData(count + 1)
        print("%s is done producing\n" % self.getName())
        
class Consumer(Thread):
    
    def __init__(self, cell, accessCount, sleepMax):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.accessCount = accessCount
        self.cell = cell
        self.sleepMax = sleepMax
        
    def run(self):

        print("%s starting up" % self.getName())
        for count in range(self.accessCount):
            time.sleep(random.randint(1, self.sleepMax))
            value = self.cell.getData()
        print("%s is done consuming\n" % self.getName())
        
def main():
    accessCount = int(input("Enter the number of accesses: "))
    sleepMax = 4
    cell = SharedCell()
    
    producer = Producer(cell, accessCount, sleepMax)
    consumer = Consumer(cell, accessCount, sleepMax)
    consumerTwo = Consumer(cell, accessCount, sleepMax)
    
    threads = []
    threads.append(producer)
    threads.append(consumer)
    threads.append(consumerTwo)
    
        
    print("Starting the threads")      
   
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
        thread.join()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `join` function blocks the current thread and waits until the indicated thread terminates.  In your loop at the end of your `main` function, why do you `join` each thread immediately after starting it?  That would result in starting thread 1, and then waiting for it to terminate before starting thread 2, and then waiting that it to terminate before starting thread 3, and so on.

Perhaps you meant something like this:

```
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

so that every thread is started before you wait for them to terminate.

Comment: This prevents the program from hanging, however each consumer does not access each producer output before continuing

Comment: EDIT: the program still hangs, removing the .join() prevents hanging however leaves the problem of the consumers accessing the producers output before continuation.

Comment: Is each item that is produced supposed to be consumed by EVERY consumer or just by SOME consumer?  Normally, I believe the assumption is that each item that is produced is going to just be consumed once.  But, you have two consumers, and each one appears to have a loop that repeats until it has consumed by itself `accessCount` items, which is never going to happen since you only have one producer and only produced a total of `accessCount` items.

Comment: Hey, me and everyone in my class are pretty much at a loss for this assignment "Re-do the producer/consumer program so that it allows multiple consumers. Each consumer must be able to consume the same data before the producer produces more data."

Comment: OK, that sounds reasonable.  So, you are going to need to track how many times each item has been consumed, and make sure that an item isn't consumed twice by the same consumer.  You could add extra data fields to your cells to track such things.  Or, perhaps, you could make each consumer also be a producer, so after consuming data it produced a new data item that would be consumed by a different consumer?